# How can I stop auto uploading of managed_file elements?

Tags: 8, forms, files

I am trying to create a field to upload the xml format of site map. But when I add a file to my filed it automatically uploaded and saved in the S3 bucket before I click on the submit button.

The issue is when someone added a xml file to that field and then closes the tab without submitting the form. The xml file is already uploaded to S3 bucket that way.

I need a way to manually upload this. I need to upload the image only after I pressed the submit button in the form. Without uploading the xml file automatically when selecting.

This is my buildForm() function.

```
public function buildForm(array $form, FormStateInterface $form_state) {

  $form['sitemap'] = [
    '#type'              => 'managed_file',
    '#name'              => 'sitemap',
    '#title'             => t('Upload Site Map (xml)'),
    '#upload_location'   => 's3://private/sitemap',
    '#field_suffix'      => 'XML format supported',
    '#upload_validators' => [
      'file_validate_extensions' => ['xml'],
    ],
    '#required'          => TRUE,
    '#validated'         => TRUE,
  ];

  $form['submit'] = [
    '#type'       => 'submit',
    '#value'      => t('Save configuration'),
    '#attributes' => [],
    '#validated'  => TRUE,
  ];

  return $form;
}
```

Comment: That should be okay imho. There was extra work done in order to achieve the functionality of auto-upload as it improves the UX process a lot. The uploaded files are saved with a `status` of `0` and are mostly cleared on cron run.

Comment: @AjitS Yes true, but there are some things that I want to do before uploading the xml. I can write that in `submitForm(array &$form, FormStateInterface $form_state)`. But the thing is it only executes after I clicked on the submit button. Is there a way to do it before auto upload happens?

Comment: Override the #attached or remove the "file/drupal.file" library from it or write js that overrides the Drupal.behaviors.fileAutoUpload

Comment: @IvanJaros Could you please elaborate more. I have found `Drupal.behaviors.fileAutoUpload`. But I don't know to edit it

Comment: I have found a way !! Drupal has a hidden submit button for upload the file automatically. Remove that button with jquery or js so the file won't upload automatically. You can find the button with inspect element. The button has the class `js-hide button js-form-submit form-submit`. Peace !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have stopped the managed_file auto uploading this way. This is like a workaround. But this works. You better put this in the `$(document).ready` in the js file.

```
(function($) {
    $(document).ready(function() {
        /*Drupal has a hidden submit button for upload the file 
          automatically. This will remove the button so Drupal won't auto upload for the given managed_file field*/
        $("input[name*='name_of_the_button']").remove();
    });
}(jQuery));
```

note - make sure you find the correct button. This is not your upload file button. This is the button that drupal creates automatically to do the file upload. This button is not visible in the page. So you need to go the inspect element and find this button. The button has the class `js-hide button js-form-submit form-submit`. So you won't miss !

Comment: It work to remove only hide button. But on saving form data, image will  not be saved as its not working for me.

Answer (score 4):

Try overriding the #attached library on the managed file field:

```
$form['sitemap'] = [
'#type'              => 'managed_file',
'#name'              => 'sitemap',
'#title'             => t('Upload Site Map (xml)'),
'#upload_location'   => 's3://private/sitemap',
'#field_suffix'      => 'XML format supported',
'#upload_validators' => [
  'file_validate_extensions' => ['xml'],
],
'#required'          => TRUE,
'#validated'         => TRUE,
'#attached'          => [
   'library' => [],
 ]
```

];

Comment: This works perfectly.